# unable to check if the user has logged in php

Tags: php

i have a master page where all my menus are in and m unable to check if the user has logged in or no this is what i have so far

**functions.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();

function loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
            return true;
        }else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }

 ?>
```

**Masterpage.php**

```
if(!loggedin()){
echo "log out";
}else{
echo "log in";
}
```

but this doesn't work for some reason i am always shown with the Logout option
i have tried changing the if statement but no success.

Comment: You never start a session with `session_start();`.

Comment: Very unclear if you actually set the `user_id` anywhere and how.

Comment: yes i have setted the `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to start a session with `session_start()` before checking th session, and to make sure that the session has been opened with the correct name and value.

Also you can optimize your function to:

```
function loggedin(){
    return !empty($_SESSION['user_id']);
}
```

Comment: could you be more clear please i didnt understand, and m sure m calling it by the correct name and value

Comment: @craftx27 have started the session at the top of the page? 
`session_start();`